# ReactiveObject properties using Objects

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, reactiveui

Is there a way to use objects as properties in ReactiveUI?

This doesn't work:

```
private Settings settings;
public Settings Settings
{
    get
    {
        return settings;
    }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref settings, value); }
}
```

I never recieve change notification when listening:

```
this.WhenActivated(
            registerDisposable =>
            {
                registerDisposable(
                        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Settings)
                        .SelectMany(async x => await _settingsService.CreateSetting(Settings))
                       .Subscribe());
            });
```

Comment: this should work, but why are you using `SelectMany` ?

Comment: @AdriánRomero Ok, well maybe it's a bug then.  I'm using the latest beta version 17.  It will not work unless I use a primitive.  I'll post a bug in ReactiveUI Github.  I'm using `SelectMany` because Paul Bets says never to use async await in `Subscribe`.

Comment: You're right in using `SelectMany`. I would however just return the `Task` directly like this: `.SelectMany(x => _settingsService.CreateSetting(Settings))`. How is `Settings` set? Might it be that you're not actually updating the reference of the property, just it's properties? Can you post the code the code that sets it (`Settings = ...`)?